# How does server pipe() a JSON object to my AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am building a web application using angularJS with Node.js backend. I am new to them both and after several attempts, I made it work to let Node.js request a JSON (using request module) and sent it to angular. However, I am pretty confused about how it works.

Here is my code,

Node.js:

```
app.get('/query', function(req, res){
    if (!req.query.func) { // query TIME_SERIES_DAILY
    var request_url = 'http://API';
    var data = request(request_url);
    console.log(typeof data); // Object
    data.pipe(res);
{
```

AngularJS:

```
myControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/query').then(function successCallback(data) {
    console.log(typeof data); // Object
}, function errorCallback(data) {
    // error msg
   });
}]);
```

After I console.log() the type of data at both ends, they are all "Object". In my understanding, both of them parsed JSON string into JSON object (if I was wrong please correct me). But how did node.js pipe() an object? (In my understanding only stream can be piped)

Can anyone explain it for me? Thanks!

Comment: Have not tried nodejs streams implementation. What does `request()` return?

Comment: I think it's because of prototyping inheritance in javascript. So to get the correct type try to check its constructor type `console.log(data.constructor.name)`, or if you know what the type you are expecting for (for example Stream) check in this way `console.log(data instance of Stream)`.

Comment: @guest271314 request() returns a request object encapsulating all headers and data etc. It has a function member named pipe()...

Comment: @TelmanAgababov great I'll try